# Rails database undefined nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to adjust an old rails project.

It generates an excel file from a database.

A contact can be linked to a company or not.
If it is linked to the company and defaultaddress is set on the company the excel sheet only prints the contact info of the company.

What I need to do is that in this case I need to export both the private contact info plus the company info to the excel sheet.

I found the file where the excel generation takes place and simply wanted to write something like this:

```
<% @defaultaddress_id = Contact.find(qc.contact.id).defaultaddress_id %>
<% @address = Address.find(@defaultaddress_id) unless @defaultaddress.empty? %>
<%= @address %>
```

(I tested just printing the defaultaddress_id, and this is just fine.)

But I find this in the logs;

```
ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass) on line #87 of app/views/query/_report.html.erb:
```

So I tried with following;

```
<% @address = Address.find(@defaultaddress_id) unless @defaultaddress_id == 0 %>
```

But now it sais

```
ActionView::TemplateError (Couldn't find Address without an ID) on line #87 of app/views/query/_report.html.erb:
```

Isn't that exactly what I am writing? Don't do the method unless there is something in the FK field?

The defaultaddress_id is the FK of the Adress table.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but you apparently already have an `contact` object, so there is no need to do `Contact.find(...)`. You can simply do: `@defaultaddress_id = qc.contact.defaultaddress_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `@defaultaddress` should be `@defaultaddress_id`

And also use `.blank?` instead to `.empty?` in case of ***nil*** values.

```
<% @address = Address.find(@defaultaddress_id) unless @defaultaddress_id.blank? %>


nil.empty?
  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass

nil.blank?
  #=> true
```